# No sound after upgrading to 16.04 LTS from 14.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Earlier today I decided to upgrade to the new LTS version of Ubtuntu (16.04) from the one I was using at the time (14.04). The installation process went rather smoothly, only dropping a few errors regarding some fglrx packages I installed back in 14.04 for my PowerColor Radeon R9 380 4GB PCS+ card to properly work in 14.04.

So after running through the upgrade and logging back in I proceeded as usual going online and reading some stuff when I noticed that there was no audio being output from my monitor (connected via HDMI to my card). So I started to look online and found similar articles about people having audio issues after an update and started performing all of the steps they followed, all without any luck.

Some examples I did:

- Removing & Reinstalling pulse & alsa
- Checking that the correct device was selected and not muted
- Going into pulsemixer and checking the device was not muted
- Reinstalling the package managers and running update commands

Obviously this is an annoying problem and I'd love to have this fixed, but if anything else fails, I'll just do a fresh install of 16.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did some more digging and it turns out that fglrx handled all of the important driver update stuff for the PowerColor Radeon cards, a quick google search turned up their respective driver page and the updated one for Ubuntu 16.04 which uses the new AMD updates.

Instructions can be found here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Once I followed the installation steps there and did a restart, everything is back up and working again!

Comment: Good work finding the answer. Two things come to mind. Firstly, other users in AskUbuntu with no sound on AMD after upgrade would like to hear your solution.  I up-voted your answer so hopefully that draws more attention. Secondly, a bug report should be filed.